# Why can't I SSH to this AWS NAT instance in a public subnet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

For experimentation purposes, I’m trying to setup an AWS EC2 inside a VPC that has both public and private subnets as described in [**this**](https://cloudpages.wordpress.com/2013/08/05/ssh-to-an-instance-in-private-subnet/) tutorial.

However, when I try to SSH in step #2, it fails (Operation times out. Connection failure):

```
$ ssh -i MyKeyFile.pem ec2-user@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
ssh: connect to host XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX port 22: Operation timed out
```

and:

```
$ telnet XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX 22
Trying XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX...
telnet: connect to address XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX: Operation timed out
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong? Why cannot I connect to this NAT EC2 as described in the tutorial? It seems like it should be simple

Comment: Please verify your security group is correct and report back.

Comment: Yes. The problem was that there was no inbound SSH route on the NAT. Adding one allowed me to SSH successfully. The tutorial I followed omitted this crucial step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several factors stopping you to do an SSH into NAT instance - please check the following items.

1. Internet Gateway is attached and is added in the route table of the Subnet ( or Main Route table )
2. Check if the NAT's  security group is open to your local on Premises ( for simplicity try with 0.0.0.0/0 )
3. Is Elastic IP is attached to the NAT instance - to established communication to / via. NAT

Comment: Yes. The problem was that there was no inbound SSH route on the NAT. Adding one allowed me to SSH successfully. The tutorial I followed omitted this crucial step.

Comment: I don't know what happend but i couldn't use ssh connect (with Teraterm) to login my NAT instance even though i opened port 22 in my nat-securitygroup with source from 0.0.0.0/0